# Why memory clean only if I press home button and back on Android device?

Tags: java, android, listview, memory

I have listView and custom ArrayAdapter for it. In my list View are many pictures and I use strong memory cleaning:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {       
    list.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And use LazyLoader for images loading.
But after some times using my application (when I updating list) I will still got "bitmap size exceeds vm budget" error. Although if I press home button and back to application memory is cleared. How can I clear memory without it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you call [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) on all of the Bitmap objects you are no longer using to free its memory as soon as possible.

Also, use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) to create a Bitmap as small as your ImageView requires and thus saving some extra memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about [Loading Large Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). This will help avoid problems with memory leaks.